# Compare two tables and find the unmatch record

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to compare two different tables with almost desame column names and output them by marking 1 on columns with same value and 0 with indifferent values given the ID columns are untouched.

Table 1

```
ID | Value | Color
1  | good  | red
2  | bad   | blue
```

Table 2

```
ID | Value | Color
1  | any   | red
2  | bad   | blue
```

Output

```
ID | Value | Color
1  | 0     | 1
2  | 1     | 1
```

wherein, the 0 is the value with different column values.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I haven't construct any query yet. It's very confusing for me.

Comment: You can start with this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014890/comparing-data-between-two-mysql-tables-with-php - This is one of many found after Googling "compare 2 mysql tables php" (for you). *Enjoy!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.id, 
  CASE WHEN table1.value=table2.value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS value,
  CASE WHEN table1.color=table2.color THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS color
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table1.id
ORDER BY 1;
```

or shorter approach:

```
SELECT table1.id, (table1.value=table2.value) AS value, (table1.color=table2.color) AS color
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table1.id
ORDER BY 1;
```

Approach in MySQL-syntax:

```
SELECT table1.id,
  IF(table1.value=table2.value, 1, 0) AS value,
  IF(table1.color=table2.color, 1, 0) AS color
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table1.id
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Hi, i tried the query but it gives me the wrong output. Is there a way I can do it something like an IF ELSE method?

Comment: I've added the approach for MySQL database.

Comment: I got the idea and the query is now working. Thanks sir.